# Listing Categories in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm having a problem and getting an understanding of this will help me figure out Magento a bit more. I have a CMS page using 1column.phtml. I actually creating a vertical navigation system using 1column.phtml itself, not the CMS. The CMS portion of things is just being used to show some images. The design of the site dictates the layout which is why I am using a 1 column and putting the sidebar in there and not using the left.phtml file. Anyway, that's not the problem. I am trying to pull the main categories and don't quite get how to do that. I'd rather just put the code in the phtml file and not mess with the XML, but when I add the code I'm not getting anything back.

```
<?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
<?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

So I get nothing back. I also don't understand scope of these, so once I get this working, how would I pull only top level categories? Thanks!

Comment: What block does `$this` refer to?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to get a collection of categories and see where that takes you.

$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
  ->getCollection();

This code will give you every single category. You can use addAttributeToSelect and addAttributeToFilter functions to furter narrow down your categories.

From there you can foreach through the categories to display them or what whatever you want to do with it.